# What is a partial upgrade and when is it necessary?

Tags: updates, update-manager, partial-upgrade

Sometimes when I am running a development version of Ubuntu, the Software Updater will tell me that a partial upgrade is needed when I check for updates.

What is a partial upgrade, and why are they necessary? Sometimes users run into problems when doing them, so when should I run a partial upgrade, if ever?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the information provided on this web site:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/U%2B1/partial_upgrade

> **Summary**
>
> If you use Update Manager to upgrade your packages, and it
> offers to do a Partial Upgrade do not accept it without thoroughly
> checking what packages it offers to remove, upgrade and install. If
> you do, you will most likely end up removing packages that shouldn't
> be removed, and waste time and effort repairing your testing
> installation and asking for assistance.
>
> Most *Partial Upgrade* situations occur due to package archive
> inconsistencies, which will typically be resolved within a few hours.
> If your package manager is confused, and so are you, simply wait and
> hold off the updates until things settle down.
>
> **Short Version**
>
> Due to the fact that uploads to the repositories of the
> active development branch are asynchronous and uncoordinated,
> dependencies of certain packages may arrive later than the dependent
> package. This causes package management tools such as Update Manager,
> which are mainly meant to be used with stable releases of Ubuntu where
> the package archive is always consistent, to interpret the situation
> as requiring a dist-upgrade to install new packages and/or repair
> packages in a reqreinst (requires reinstallation) state. What Update
> Manager performs when doing a "Partial Upgrade" is a dist-upgrade.
>
> When testing development releases, most of the time, a *Partial Upgrade*
> is undesired. The situations where it's needed are limited to new
> packages obsoleting old ones (as in the case of the software-center
> package replacing software-store) and package removals from the
> archive.
>
> Do not assume that since you're running a development release, a
> *Partial Upgrade* is necessarily warranted.