# 22.04.2 LTS software updater is trying to do upgrades and hits some error?

Tags: apt, update-manager

This just starting happening today I think.

It makes it sound like the updater is trying to upgrade Ubuntu to some other version. apt-get update works without error.

Does anyone know if this is some weird local setting I have that is causing this, or it is expected? Or some bug in the updater?

[image]

UPDATE:

As requested

```
$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease
Hit:3 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/alex-p/tesseract-ocr-devel/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                                                                                          
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                                                                                                                            
Hit:5 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                                                                                                                    
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [119 kB]                                                                                                                                           
Hit:7 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/jgmath2000/et/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                                                                                                       
Hit:8 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2204/x86_64  InRelease                                                                                                                       
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]                                                        
Hit:10 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt kubernetes-xenial InRelease                                                                       
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages [764 kB]
Get:13 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe i386 Packages [520 kB]
Get:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe amd64 Packages [718 kB]
Hit:12 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease  
Fetched 2,232 kB in 12s (190 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
92 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

```
$ systemctl status snapd.service
● snapd.service - Snap Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/snapd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2023-04-12 09:49:49 BST; 1 week 1 day ago
TriggeredBy: ● snapd.socket
   Main PID: 1165 (snapd)
      Tasks: 27 (limit: 38386)
     Memory: 619.8M
        CPU: 1min 8.335s
     CGroup: /system.slice/snapd.service
             └─1165 /usr/lib/snapd/snapd

Apr 20 04:59:49 xxx snapd[1165]: no snap revision available as specified: "lbry"
Apr 20 04:59:49 xxx snapd[1165]: snap not found: "stickynotes"
Apr 20 04:59:49 xxx snapd[1165]: snapstate.go:1778: cannot refresh snap "firefox": snap "firefox" has running apps (firefox), pids: 1127902,1127905,2253589,2253862,2253891,2253908,2254006,2255129
Apr 20 04:59:49 xxx snapd[1165]: autorefresh.go:551: auto-refresh: all snaps are up-to-date
Apr 20 06:49:49 xxx snapd[1165]: storehelpers.go:769: cannot refresh:
Apr 20 06:49:49 xxx snapd[1165]: snap has no updates available: "bare", "core", "core18", "core20", "core22", "foliate", "gitter-desktop", "gnome-3-26-1604", "gnome-3-28-1804", "gnome-3-34-1804", "gnome-3>
Apr 20 06:49:49 xxx snapd[1165]: no snap revision available as specified: "lbry"
Apr 20 06:49:49 xxx snapd[1165]: snap not found: "stickynotes"
Apr 20 06:49:50 xxx snapd[1165]: snapstate.go:1778: cannot refresh snap "firefox": snap "firefox" has running apps (firefox), pids: 1127902,1127905,2253589,2253862,2253891,2253908,2254006,2255129
Apr 20 06:49:50 xxx snapd[1165]: autorefresh.go:551: auto-refresh: all snaps are up-to-date
```

Comment: It's perfectly normal and happens all the time. Just press the "Partial Upgrade" button. It's badly worded, but it should resolve the issue.

Comment: Please show us `sudo apt update` also `systemctl status snapd.service` through [edit].

Comment: @nobody updated

Comment: please remove all Packages from foreign sources. And reinstall `snap` Afterwards `sudo apt full-upgrade` to upgrade your system complete. Then try again to make the release-upgrade.

Comment: Uppsie forgot disable all foreign sources after removeing the packages.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a partial upgrade and when is it necessary?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/443788/what-is-a-partial-upgrade-and-when-is-it-necessary)

Comment: Screen res, drivers etc busted now after whatever reboot/update. Obviously it was a hint that something was about to blow up.

Comment: @nobody can you clarify what you mean? My system is now in a mostly broken state with graphics drivers now off. Am looking for commands or even hastily typed approximations of commands.

Comment: totally busted setup now. Going to try to upgrade but even that seems to be abnormal. Need very precise bail out commands else I can just google.

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/upgrading-ubuntu-desktop#2-launch-the-software-updater

This is invalid?